# How to get the row index value after clicking on a delete button?

Tags: html, jquery

I have dynamically created rows and would like any row to be deleted accordingly.

```
var markup = "";
markup += '<tr>';
markup += '<td>' + result.data[0].firstName + result.data[0].lastName + result.data[0].jobTitle+ result.data[0].email + '</td>';
markup += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editPersonnelModal" data-id = '+result.data[0].id+'> <i class="fa-solid fa-pencil fa-fw"> </i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm deletePersonnelBtn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deletePersonnelModal" data-id= '+ result.data[0].id+ '> <i class="fa-solid fa-trash fa-fw"></i> </td>';
markup += '</tr>';
$("table tbody").append(markup);
```

I have a boostrap modal which displays a message for the delete button which I am trying to retrieve the index value but to no avail.

Delete Employee

```
  <div class="modal-body">
      
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type = "button" id = "deleteRow" class = "btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm myBtn" data-bs-dismiss="modal"> DELETE </button>
    <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm myBtn" data-bs-dismiss = "modal"> CANCEL </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$("#deletePersonnelModal").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
    $('#deleteRow').on("click",function(){
        var index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
        alert(index)
    }); 
});
```

The index value keeps showing 0 for all the rows and not its corresponding value, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not mentioned in any existing answers:  *keeps showing 0* - this is because `id`s *must* be unique, so `$("#deleteRow")` finds only the *first* one every time and that is on the first (0-based) row.

Answer (score 0):

i don't find the id 'deleteRow' in the code

for the index() function, please refer to jQuery : https://api.jquery.com/index/

This example will help you :

```
<ul>
  <li id="foo">foo</li>
  <li id="bar">bar</li>
  <li id="baz">baz</li>
</ul>
```

If we retrieve one of the three list items (for example, through a DOM function or as the context to an event handler), .index() can search for this list item within the set of matched elements:

```
var listItem = document.getElementById( "bar" );
alert( "Index: " + $( "li" ).index( listItem ) );
```

Result => Index: 1

So for your problem i see something like :

```
$('#deleteRow').on("click",function(){
    //assuming 'deleteRow' is first child of td
    var trparent = $(this).parent().parent();
    var tableparent = trparent.parent();
    var index = tableparent.index(trparent);
    alert(index);
});
```

NB : i prefer debugging with console.log : console.log("index", index);
NB2 : don't forget 0 is the value for first index

Keep me informed if it helped :)
Regards

Comment: I have updated my question and it didn't hep unfortunately.

Comment: on click on button, do a each loop on tr elements. your code does not make sense at this time

Answer (score -1):

Use `closest` and make sure you spell the ID/classNames correctly.

In this code we do not need the ID to delete

```js
const result = {
  data: [
    {
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Doe",
      jobTitle: "Software Engineer",
      email: "john.doe@example.com",
      id: 1
    },
    {
      firstName: "Jane",
      lastName: "Doe",
      jobTitle: "Software Engineer",
      email: "jane.doe@example.com",
      id: 2
    }
  ]
};
var markup = result.data.map(person => `<tr>
  <td>${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}: ${person.email}</td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editPersonnelModal" data-id="${ person.id}"><i class="fa-solid fa-pencil fa-fw"></i></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm deletePersonnelBtn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deletePersonnelModal" data-id="${person.id}"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash fa-fw"></i> 
  </td>
</tr>`);
$("table tbody").append(markup);

$('.deletePersonnelBtn').on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css"  />

<table><tbody></tbody></table>
```

Bootstrap modal version

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css">
<table class="table">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<!-- Delete Personnel Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="deletePersonnelModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="deletePersonnelModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="deletePersonnelModalLabel">Confirm Deletion</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Are you sure you want to delete this personnel?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="confirmDeleteBtn">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
  const result = {
    data: [{
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe",
        jobTitle: "Software Engineer",
        email: "john.doe@example.com",
        id: 1
      },
      {
        firstName: "Jane",
        lastName: "Doe",
        jobTitle: "Software Engineer",
        email: "jane.doe@example.com",
        id: 2
      }
    ]
  };

  var markup = result.data.map(person => `<tr>
            <td>${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}: ${person.email}</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editPersonnelModal" data-id="${ person.id}"><i class="fa-solid fa-pencil fa-fw"></i></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm deletePersonnelBtn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deletePersonnelModal" data-id="${person.id}"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash fa-fw"></i> Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>`);

  $("table tbody").append(markup);

  $('.deletePersonnelBtn').on("click", function() {
    // Store the reference to the current row
    var $rowToDelete = $(this).closest("tr");

    // Set up a click event handler for the "Delete" button in the modal
    $('#confirmDeleteBtn').off('click').on('click', function() {
      // Perform the deletion here using the stored reference
      $rowToDelete.remove();
      // Close the modal
      $('#deletePersonnelModal').modal('hide');
    });
  });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, this works however when the user clicks on the deletePersonnelBtn it should open the boostrap modal and then delete the record.`$("#deletePersonnelModal").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {  $('.deletePersonnelBtn').on("click", function() {    $(this).closest("tr").remove()  }); });` ***Ive tried the following but it doesn't work, any ideas on how to go about this?***

Comment: See updated code